# Typescript/Javascript: mailto with subject, body and array of links

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I work on Angular 4. On click of hyperlink I have to open outlook, in the mail I will have to send 4 links. So I have planned to call a `mailto` from my typescript file. My code is

```
    <span (click)="mailMe()">Mail me the links</span>


    var links= ["link1.com", "link2.com", "link3.com"];
    mailMe(){
        console.log("111111");
        var mail = document.createElement("a");
        console.log("22222");
        mail.href = "mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=files&body=Hi";
        mail.click();
    }
```

I am able to call the function but mail is not popping up. In console `111111` is getting printed but `22222` is not getting printed. Where did I go wrong? OR is there a way I can send the array of links from HTML itself?

Comment: I am not able to see any array which you want to send there

Comment: why don't you use an anchor tag it self instead of  the span like `<a [href]="your mailto text">Mail me the links</a>` and set the `href` in typescript.

Comment: In which navigator are you trying ? I just tested in Chrome and its working. Some navigators need to inject the element in the real dom (by doing `document.body.insertBefore(mail, currentDiv);` for example.

Comment: @Niladri Is it safe to write such a long content on HTML. And if so how to iterate over the link array on HTML?

Comment: @SébastienOllivier I work on IE and have to target IE only no other browser

Comment: @Anna i am asking you to use attribute binding and set the value of `href` in typescript not in HTML.

Comment: It seems to work with IE11. What you IE version ? Do you have some plugin to disable popup, etc. ?

Comment: @Anna check my answer for chrome and older version of IE

Comment: @SébastienOllivier my IE version is alos 11 but email not popping up

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 18):

you want to achieve like this

```
<a href="mailto:xyz@example.com?Subject=Hello&body=links:  %0D 
         http://link1.com  %0D http://link1.com " target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

in angular you can do it like this , in html

```
<a [href]="emailstring" target="_top"></a>
```

in ts file do like this

```
 emailstring= "mailto:xyz@example.com?Subject=Hello&body=links:  %0D 
             http://link1.com  %0D http://link1.com";
```

Haven't tested with angular but check it with pure html.  and its working on chrome.

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve this in IE with a simple `window.location.href` as IE has some weird behavior with `mailto` .Here I am using the same `<span>` from your code with the `links` array.

**Example code for IE :**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
     <span (click)="mailMe()">Mail me the links on (click)</span>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'test';
  links : any[]= ["link1.com", "link2.com", "link3.com"];

  mailText:string = "";

  mailMe(){
    this.mailText = "mailto:abc@abc.com+?subject=files&body="+this.links.join(" ,"); // add the links to body
    window.location.href = this.mailText;
  }

}
```

The below example might not work in IE but it's tested in Chrome. Here i have used anchor tag and set the `href` attribute in typescript.

**Example for Chrome and others**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
     <a [href]="mailText">Mail me the links</a> <br>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'test';
  links : any[]= ["link1.com", "link2.com", "link3.com"];

  mailText:string = "";


  ngOnInit(){
    this.mailText = "mailto:abc@abc.com+?subject=files&body="+this.links.join(" ,");
  }

}
```

Here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/attribute-binding-1-7wncwf

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple HTML JavaScript code. This will help you to write your own.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function mailMe (mail) // <--- element on which you need to apply click
    {
        mail = document.createElement("a");
        mail.href = "mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=files&body=Hi";
        mail.click();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span onClick = "mailMe(this);" >  <!-- pass it from here -->
         Mail me the links
    </span >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why to put pure javascript code , it can be achievable with angular itself , i think better to keep simple ,

Comment: This is not relevant to angular.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a function from the template to achieve more complexe variable building

```
<a [href]="mailto('example@mail.com', 'newSubject')">
```

Then in your TS file just return the proper anchor href string

```
mailto(emailAddress: string, emailSubject: any) {
    return "mailto:" + emailAddress + "?subject=" + emailSubject
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the body content the question asked about.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="mailto:{{email}}">Contact via E-mail</a>
```

this works in HTML file of an angular app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You forgot to include the subject line and email body that the question was asking about.

Answer (score -2):

To create a Mailto link, you need to use the HTML  tag with its href attribute, and insert a "mailto:" parameter after it, like the following:

```
<a href="mailto:username@gmail.com">
```

or

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=username@gmail.com" target="_blank">username@gmail.com</a>
```

Comment: The OP already knows how to use `mailto:`, the question is more specifically asking how to include specific text for the email body. How does your answer solve that problem? Is your answer adding anything of value over the existing answers from 3 years ago?