# Can I implement a Gmail adress as a link to a png?

Tags: html, css, email

It worked once but since I added more links (Twitter and Instagram) it doesn't work anymore.
This is the CSS Code for my gmail links:

```
  .gmail {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And this is the div:

```
<div class="gmail">
  <a href="mailto:emailexample@gmail.com" title="Gmail">
    <img alt="Gmail" src="gmail-logo-transparent-background-2-removebg-preview.png" width="100" height="100" />
</a>
</div>
```

I tried multiple emails but it never worked so the email shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Check this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129707/href-mailto-is-not-working-on-any-of-the-browsers

Comment: I already have set the default email client. The problem is that the title ("Gmail") doesn't pop up if I hover over the png. For example if I hover over the Twitter png the box "Twitter" appears and I can click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out they were to close to another. I changed the width of the instagram png to 250px instead of 300 and the box's left margin edge to 70% so that there ,,hitboxes" doesn't collide.

Answer (score 1):

`mailto` links have a fairly good support across email clients. But as with everything, be aware that it might not work. You can check [support for `mailto` links on caniemail.com](https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-mailto-links/).

Comment: Everything seems to be supported.. I'll figure something out. But thanks for the link!